# Profile page is very empty, revert to old version?

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

This is what my profile page looks like:

| Before today | Today |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before redesign] | [image: After redesign] |

There is a lot of blank space on the right side where the links/stats used to be. Can we put it back there?

Comment: Related MSE announcement: [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285)

Comment: The loss of the last seen data is extremely disappointing. I use that all the time when commenting/voting/editing etc so I can know if the question author has seen requests for more information or comments, whether a question has been abandoned by its author, etc.

Comment: The idea is that one does not post answers "for the question author", but "for the repository". Less focus on the OP history (last seen, member for how long), is a good thing, IMO.

Comment: @yivi I agree with you. I may dislike some of the changes and some of the effects afterwards but I don't think the "stalking information" and vanity information was very valuable. Although, the "member from" did have some uses for detecting spammers.

Comment: @yivi: My use case isn't related to posting answers for the author, it is holding back on downvotes and close votes (especially for new users) until it is obvious that they have been back to the site since their question was posted and commented on, and that they have seen comments and chosen to ignore suggestions for improvement or have genuinely abandoned their question, knowing that a downvote would trigger roomba, for example

Comment: @talonmies I agree, for me it's a difference between hasn't seen the inquiries for more details -> continue waiting or has seen but ignored it -> down and closevote Edit: wrote my comment before your latest as a reply to your first one and it's exactly what I mean.

Comment: You should vote as soon as possible, @talonmies. Those actions can be reverted if the user comes back and add the necessary clarifications. And Roomba is very far from instantaneous. There is no practical difference between "saw the comment asking for clarification and ignored it" vs "never came back thus never saw the comment". In both cases the content needs to be moderated. If the user ever comes back and address the feedback, a post can be reopened, a downvote removed, etc. "Follow" those that you think are more likely to receive love from their author. "Last seen" is useless for this.

Comment: @yivi theoretically you're right, downvotes can be removed, posts can be reopened, but practically? I guess we all know the defects of the queue, esp. the reopen queue and also that most downvoters don't ever revert a downvote.

Comment: While I don't disagree with your conclusion that there's a lot of whitespace, the difference in content which you have in the "about me" section for your two examples also tends to make the current view substantially worse than it would be with the same content. Note that I'm not saying the current look is good, merely that the content makes the images you've used for comparison biased wrt. what you're specifically comparing.

Comment: @Makyen good point. I had added all the "asd asd asd"s because I was wondering how long profile about-mes would scroll, but I forgot to remove it. Removed now.

Comment: If this can't be reverted i.e. last seen etc, then at least have a glyph showing the user is online or offline.  One of the main attractions in SO is its liveliness which would be gone if nobody knows whether the question asker or the person responding is online  -> less number of votes as some body may post a questioin and disappear for a year -> less stimulation to answer -> i.e. people may migrate to other sites.