# How can we find "last seen" and "profile views" info on the profile page now that they are gone?

Tags: support, profile-page, views, last-seen

Today the layout of the user profile page has changed. I haven't found any information on MSO about it.

Now that it's gone, how can we find "last seen" and "profile views" information in profiles?

---

And those blanks are also a little uncomfortable:

[image: screenshot of Martijn Pieters's profile]

Comment: Feel free to join in on the collective bafflement regarding the change on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/786798

Comment: Someone else also [just asked this here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410617/will-new-design-of-profile-page-not-include-last-visited-field).

Comment: But.. you can't move it there. That where the *very important* collective information has a placeholder!

Comment: see also [Profile page is very empty, revert to old version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410612)

Comment: this needs to be [meta-tag:featured] to help wider site audience learn about the change and [get to where this all started](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/165773). And support [request to roll it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368312/165773)

Comment: I think questions like this, although technically 'duplicates' of the one linked by @Oleg, ***should*** be posted **as often as possible on every site's Meta** (adding the `bug` and `feature-request` tags) until the recent changes to the Profile Page are reverted.

Comment: @AdrianMole I actually agree with that sentiment - the more ruckus there is regarding the change, the better, even if some will ultimately be closed as dupes of early reports such as this. That's the only way we have to show SE how unwise this decision has been.

Comment: @Oleg Yep! In the past, the active "Meta Community" has been called "toxic" by senior staff who didn't agree with what that Community was asking for. Time to get toxic, again?

Comment: @AdrianMole there is already a [tag:feature-request] for this - [Bring the "last seen" field back on "profile" page, please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410617).

Comment: @AdrianMole oh, we already are :) Hope all this is going to get through just as it did with "thank you" and custom 404 pages gone. The way how the change was made shows utter disregard for community input.

Comment: @Oleg The Thanks™ misadventure was from a different team - one that *did* listen. This latest mess is from the team that changed line spacing and, despite much protestation, never once even considered reverting the change.

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah, that's true. Although Aaron has shown willingness to revert changes when it turned out that custom 404s are actually a beloved feature. If we all concentrate on making it loud and clear that this is not about the UI/UX being good/bad (as I see how it can actually have the effect of the team doubling-down on the decision) but the decisions made went against everything community stands for and what SE has been trying to convince us for the past months they support too, it might just work.

Comment: @zcoop98 I swear I fixed that typo before submitting... Freudian slip!

Comment: It partly came back. As this is being used as a duplicate target, it ought to be indicated somehow. [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4377851/daviddev): *"Last seen more than 4 years ago"*

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) provides a way to get this information through the [/users/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) endpoint:

```js
const endpoint = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/";
$(btn).on('click', function() {
  const params = "?order=desc&site=" + sitename.value + "&filter=!40D72h-7nG92Z1_td";
  const url = endpoint + userid.value + params;
  $.get(url, function(response) {
    if (response.items.length == 0) {
      $(result).html("No user with that id found");
    } else {
      const userData = response.items[0];
      const lastSeen = new Date(userData.last_access_date * 1000);
      const viewCount = userData.view_count;
      const joinDate = new Date(userData.creation_date * 1000);
      $(result).html("Last seen: " + lastSeen.toLocaleString() + "<br>Profile views: " + viewCount + "<br>Member since: " + joinDate.toLocaleString());
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Sitename: <input placeholder="site-name" id="sitename" value="stackoverflow">
<br/><br/> User ID: <input type="number" placeholder="user-id" id="userid">
<button id="btn">Check</button>
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
```

---

A userscript that I wrote ([LegacyProfiles](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats)) is available that automatically loads this information when you view a user's profile.

Comment: Great user script. There is a minor bug though: it uses plural even when it should be singular, for example "last seen 1 hour**s** ago" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6agHo.png)). It's not a big deal, but it would be nice if you could fix it if it's not too difficult.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Thanks for the report. Patched in [v1.8](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/LegacyProfiles/v1.8)

Comment: Hi @Spectric. I really like the script. Minor Bug though: when you press check without writing something in the input then this will be displayed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eGrA.png

Comment: OK..., works..., finally...!, some Instructions missing on the SE Post, => first need to install '[TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)', I didn't/won't upvote (yet), (+ can't vote/comment on SE, need 100-Rep, only have 99-Rep), but I **never** upvote when People use "recent"/"last"/"latest". + not clear what the Links on "Un/Minified" are, => simply open some '.js' File as '.txt' File in the Browser... // But OK, it works "in the end" (v2.2 'Unminified' on FF98)... Doesn't work though in FF55 + 'Greasemonkey' v4.1. (+0.9 then, ah-ah...!)

Comment: Alright, still got my Upvote, ah-ah...!, nice to get the `Last seen` Info back, that's useful (needed!) Info for Answerers to deal with the Follow-up from Askers... (and to be more patient), and I had "forgotten" about the `Profile Views`, ah-ah...! // Script in v2.2. is quite different from the one posted in this Answer, I might "tweak" it to display the Date in International Format (`2022-06-05`) rather than the current "`06/05/2022`", + split the long Lines to make the Script a bit more readable without Horizontal Scrolling, but it works nicely... // How much is the `API Limit` btw...?

Comment: @chivracq The API limit is 300, but it can be extended to 10000 if you register an API key.

Comment: OK, API Key can be registered [here](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) indeed, not "clear" what needs to be filled in for `OAuth Domain` and `Enable Client Side OAuth Flow`, but I haven't read any Documentation yet... // And hum, the "Default" Script v2.2. already contains an API Key ("`LRILX...`"), so I guess all Users using the "Default" Script share the 10,000 Calls for that Default API Key together... OK, I'll "see" with more Practice if I need to register a "Personal" API Key..., or 300 would already be more than enough for myself alone... That's per Day I reckon...

Comment: This does not work. I just typed some random alphabets and I gave a result which is not valid. See [this](https://ibb.co/jwrZCDK) image

Comment: Typing out random strings into numeric inputs and taking advantage of the browser-specific behavior of allowing non-digits, then claiming "this does not work" is a bit unfair to the userscript, @Sambhav.K. Do feel free to submit a bug report on the Stack Apps post, though.

Answer (score 26):

Here’s a solution for last seen:

In the user’s profile, click on "network profile" in the top right and then look at their accounts tab. This won’t show the exact time of day they visited, and I don’t think all users have a network profile, but it’s something.

Here’s yours, for an example: https://stackexchange.com/users/16353407/jizhihaosama?tab=accounts

Comment: I think there is a bug in it. "Last seen" seems to be capped at 25 days. For instance, I don't think I have visited any of the obscure cryptocurrency sites in the last 25 days, like "EOS.IO" (or "Martial Arts" or "Esperanto Language"). Abandoned accounts can't be detected this way.

Comment: Mine is properly showing dates well past 25 days (scroll to the bottom, tested while not logged in): https://stackexchange.com/users/6979/james-skemp?tab=accounts

Comment: A user can be a member of 50 sites but if they decide to hide their 49 accounts on each site, visitors will only see one community on the profile page's "communities" and that user won't have a network account (which is daft because being a member of one site surely means you have an account on the network). This means it's impossible to view a person's last activity on *any* of the sites they participate in.