# "Last seen" information removed in new profile design?

Tags: discussion, design

Since the change of profile tab design (I assume three or four days ago), I've noticed the disappearance of the "last seen" information.

As it is shown in the below old design:

[image]

Is it definitively removed or will it be added later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could we know "last seen" and "profile views" in profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410618/how-could-we-know-last-seen-and-profile-views-in-profile)

Comment: MSE announcement: [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive)