# "Last seen" was important

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

There are 2 degradations I have experienced since this metric was removed.

1. When quickly interacting with another user, especially on some content produced a long time ago, it was a really quick and easy proxy for whether a response might be forthcoming. For example, you might stick around at your keyboard a few extra minutes to complete something if you know there's a good chance the person you're interacting with has seen it and is therefore likely to respond (i.e. if their 'last seen' was within the last 30 mins), but you may go on to other things if, for example, their last seen was >12 months ago.
2. It gives some idea as to whether an improvement to an answer has not been made because the author is no longer using the site, or whether they *chose* a very specific implementation which is superior to a more obvious implementation but for reasons which are not obvious. If the user has been last seen within the last day or so, it's likely they are active, and an '@' to them will get noticed / addressed. Whereas an '@' to an inactive user rarely gets a response. Of course, without knowing their 'last seen', you can still '@' them to clarify/improve the answer, you just have less information to predict whether you'll get a timely response.

It was useful. Consider bringing it back.

Comment: This affects the whole network, not just SO. The main discussion is on MSE. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368289/334566 and its links.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for this, the question is very broad but the top two answers seem extremely supportive (better than I could have articulated!) of the “Last seen” value. Is there any update from SE as to whether it will be put back?

Comment: @PM2Ring I see the top two answers are of scores 328 and 282, but I have insufficient rep to see the total up/down of each. I would be interested to know these figures to understand whether there is significant numbers in opposition to the display of the value.

Comment: @stevec 335/7 and 289/7 respectively. There is mostly no opposition for this - most of us are appalled by the decision to remove it

Comment: Here's a userscript you can install (on some browsers) to see the up / down vote breakdown: https://stackapps.com/q/8166 FWIW, that question is on the MSE top ten list of all-time worst negative scoring questions (not counting deleted ones).

Comment: @stevec no, there isn't, unfortunately. Aaron made a unilateral decision to remove it, then there was a comment from animuson (also staff) of the form "we got complaints, deal with it". No response other than that - it is unlikely we are getting those back, like, ever despite the pushback

Comment: I assume the opposition is primarily from people who say that the Last Seen data is an invasion of privacy. But the counter-argument is to round the Last Seen time to a larger time step, eg 6 hours or a day. There *have* been some positive responses from staff (including animuson) regarding a Last Active field that uses data that's still available on the public profile.

Comment: @PM2Ring yeah, I think the general consensus is that we can sacrifice precision if it means saving this metric - I just wish staff would listen to us...

Comment: There's a Last Seen userscript here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410627/4014959 but I don't know how long it will remain functional.

Comment: @PM2Ring FYI, in my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368889/562482), I propose basically the same idea as yours, with this being what I consider to be a reasonable compromise for the apparent main reason for removing "Last seen", i.e., privacy issues, as stated in [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)'s [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368289#comment1228272_368289).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Indeed! And I've already voted on that question & your answer. When I originally made [my suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive#comment1228486_368289) animuson [responded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive#comment1228509_368289) "I'd prefer PM 2Ring's suggestion of changing it to Last Active and showing the last time they publicly interacted with the site".

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for reminding me about your previous comment. There were so many comments on my answer there that I forgot about most of them, including yours.

Comment: @John No worries. I don't expect people to remember huge meta comment threads. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Although it's likely not a big deal to you, since you did propose a similar idea to what I wrote in my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368889/562482), I've updated it to state this.

Comment: @John Much appreciated. I just wish animuson or one of the devs would give us some more feedback on this... As you mention in that answer, the Last Seen value was never very accurate anyway, and I always suspected that was both for efficiency and privacy reasons. I used to joke that the Last Seen value is science fiction, not fact. ;)

Comment: @bad_coder well, more like "partially" restored given the reduced precision, but this is *something*

Answer (score 8):

This has been partially restored with reduced granularity see [this FR marked status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371145) with [the developer comment underneath](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile/371145#comment1241076_371145).

Comment: Is there any way to turn this off on your/my own user profile (for a site)?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I don't think so. But you can post a feature request for that.