# Option to not show detailed "last seen" in user's profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Why was the detailed activity information removed from the profile view? Previously, I could see if a user was last seen 10 minutes ago, 1 hour ago, or 1 day ago. Now this information is hidden and the most detailed information I can get about a user seems to be "this week":

[image]

I guess this change had to do with privacy(?). But could we have that as an option in the user's setting instead? Such that detailed view is on by default, and if the user wants to hide this information they can switch off the option? I think the information is useful if the user does not mind showing it.

Comment: Why should it default to divulging the most information possible?

Comment: Perhaps start out with the feature request so it doesn't look like a duplicate?

Comment: The source of the why is the now infamous "vanity metrics" post - *[Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/)* (-395. 2021-08-05. Unspecific title).

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Thanks for the link, but the other question just says *"Could we please have the "last visited" data back?"* it does not propose how to bring it back. In this question I propose making it optional for the user to reveal the information, so it is an intermediary solution between the two extremes (hiding the information for everyone, and showing the information for everyone)

Comment: @HåkonHægland The other [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411522/last-seen-was-important)

Comment: Please provide an explanation why this question was closed. I have provided my opinion why it should not be closed in my previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reopening. Btw. I found that this stack app [LegacyProfiles - Bringing back the old profile stats](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats) brings back the old behavior.. Very nice! But then I am not sure why the information was hidden in the first place when it is so easy to get it back?